# filter (where ...) that works with Postgres but not with Redshift

Tags: sql, filter, amazon-redshift, where-clause

What is the alternative for Redshift to the filter (where...) that is possible in Postgres?
I get the following error and cannot figure out whether this is not possible in Redshift or I have a syntax error:
The database reported a syntax error: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 1521;

```
select count(distinct "agent.id")  as "agent_cnt"
, count(distinct "agent.id") filter (where "agent.status" = 'active' and ("agent.date" between '2020-01-01' and current_date)) as "active_agent_cnt"
from "agent"
```

Comment: Redshift forked off from PostgreSQL before `filter(where)` was added.  If Redshift had added this feature into their fork, it seems like they would have used the same syntax, so it probably does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
count(distinct case when "agent.status" = 'active' and ("agent.date" between '2020-01-01' and current_date then "agent.id" end) as "active_agent_cnt"
```

Having periods in column names seems highly suspicious.  I would strongly discourage such a naming convention.

Comment: worth mentioning: a `case` without specified `else` returns by default `null` if no `when` is matched which works fine with count, but may cause issues with other functions --> use with cautious

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why having periods in names is suspicious. It's identifying a column by the table, and with redshift (and PG) it's also plausible it has a schema to use too, so it'd be realistic (but maybe unusual) to see `schema.table.column` identifiers.

Comment: That's actually the problem - it's not! The text inside the quotes is the column. So it's not "table.column", but it's actually "col.umn". For example, the column "agent.status" is on the "agent" table, so to identify the table and column you'd write "agent"."agent.status". This was likely a mistake/typo in the original post/question (or a very confusingly named column).